# Trying to categorize some columns and exclude others. Getting this error Cannot perform 'ror_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python, numpy, cat

I would like to exclude ratings column and `correctYear` column from getting categorized. I would like to categorize every other object type field but leave out these two because they are numeric values.

```
name            object
rating          object
genre           object
year             int64
released        object
score          float64
votes          float64
director        object
writer          object
star            object
country         object
budget         float64
gross          float64
company         object
runtime        float64
correctYear     object
dtype: object
```

below is my code

tried type casting `correctYear` but got this error

```
could not convert string to float:
```

```
df_cat = df

for col in df_cat.columns:
    if (df_cat[col].dtype=='object' & (df_cat[col]!='rating' | df_cat[col]!='correctYear')):
        df_cat[col] = df_cat[col].astype('category')
        df_cat[col] = df_cat[col].cat.codes
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: if it can't convert `string` to `float` then you should change what strings you have in column - maybe you have strings which are not float values.